# Can I create an APK and IPA file using Ionic use from Windows OS?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

My Question, I am using Windows laptop, in ionic have an option to build APK and IPA (For IOS Platform app ) file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah sure you can... You need to use cordova for it. (I am using it for some projects)

Install cordova using npm and then in project initialize cordova.

Then add platform using cordova for android and iOS in project. 
Then use Cordova to build app for android or iOS

Comment: Thanks, Pritish Kumar